# Matplotlib minor ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to customize the minor ticks in a matplotlib plot. Consider the following code:

```
import pylab as pl
from matplotlib.ticker import AutoMinorLocator

fig, ax = pl.subplots(figsize=(11., 7.4))

x = [1,2,3, 4]
y = [10, 45, 77, 55]
errorb = [20,66,58,11]

pl.xscale("log")

ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(2))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(2))

pl.tick_params(which='both', width=1)
pl.tick_params(which='minor', length=4, color='g')
pl.tick_params(axis ='both', which='major', length=8, labelsize =20, color='r' )

pl.errorbar(x, y, yerr=errorb)
#pl.plot(x, y)

pl.show()
```

As far as I understood, `AutoMinorLocator(n)` is supposed to insert n minor ticks between each major tick, and this is what happens on a linear scale but simply cannot figure out the logic behind the placement of the minor ticks on a logscale. On the top of that, there are much more minor ticks when using `errorbar()` then when using the simple `plot()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AutoMinorLocator is only designed to work for linear scales:

From the [`ticker` documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#tick-locating):

> **AutoMinorLocator**
>
> locator for minor ticks **when the axis is linear** and the major ticks are uniformly spaced. It subdivides the major tick interval into a specified number of minor intervals, defaulting to 4 or 5 depending on the major interval.

And the [`AutoMinorLocator` documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.AutoMinorLocator):

> Dynamically find minor tick positions based on the positions of major ticks. **Assumes the scale is linear** and major ticks are evenly spaced.

You probably want to use the [`LogLocator`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.LogLocator) for your purposes.

For example, to put major ticks in base 10, and minor ticks at 2 and 5 on your plot (or every `base*i*[2,5]`), you could:

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(LogLocator(base=10))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(LogLocator(base=10,subs=[2.0,5.0]))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(2))
```

[image]

Comment: worked like a charm! thanks for the thorough answer!